# Is it possible to get a VAT refund on goods I purchased in the UK if I'm departing Europe from Paris?

Tags: tax-refunds

I've bought a smartphone from Amazon in the UK which has around 35 pounds VAT on it. I'd like to get this back when I fly from Europe to Australia, however I depart from Paris and not from the UK.

Is it possible for me to get the tax refunded and if so, how?

Comment: You ordered from Amazon UK to France? Or are you in the UK, and going to France later?

Comment: Surely you'll be leaving the UK at some point to get to France? So can't you claim it then?

Comment: I'm actually in Sweden and won't go to the UK at all. @AnkurBanerjee

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is.  You need to get your refund from the last country you're in before leaving the EU.  I assume you're having a stop over in Paris and not just transiting through.  If you're transiting, you would need to get the refund in the UK as the customs check should be outside the transit area.

> If you're travelling to another country within the EU before you
> finally leave the EU, then you must show your goods and refund form to
> customs officials in that country when you leave it.

[VAT refunds for visitors to the UK](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/vat/sectors/consumers/overseas-visitors.htm)

> 7.1.2 I'm leaving the UK for another EU country:
>
> Show your goods, till receipts and refund form to customs in the last EU country you visit.
> The deadline for exporting the goods stays the same regardless of how
> many countries you visit.

[Tax free shopping in the UK](http://customs.hmrc.gov.uk/channelsPortalWebApp/channelsPortalWebApp.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=pageVAT_ShowContent&id=HMCE_CL_000141&propertyType=document#P69_3817)